# When to use Django Workers, Queues, and Tasks rather than Python Threading or Concurrent?

Tags: python, django, concurrency

Assume on a Django projects, we want to update a user profile along with sending him/her an email notifying changes, in this case two different solutions would come in mind:

- using python concurrent library to run both tasks
- use something like [Django Q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

the project also needs "Scheduled Tasks" to be run daily or weekly, so a job Que library is a must, but I thought I could use python concurrent library for making functions run concurrently and something like [Advanced Python Scheduling](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable), this also came in mind when I realized [Dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/) does not support scheduling tasks.

now my question is :

> What are benefits of using Django Task Queuing apps over using python core libraries like concurrent?

Comment: Do not try to do your tasks in the running WSGI application instance. It might work on the development server and fail completely in a production setup with multiple processes. Use cron and custom managment commands for scheduled tasks and a task queue like celery for other time consuming tasks.

Comment: thanks @KlausD. for your comment, can you please explain what can cause failure of threaded program in multi process condition? can you introduce any references?